# Should I use GridView or RecyclerView?

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I need to create a view where products are compared (min 2, max 5). I had two thoughts:

1. Create a RecyclerView and each column would be a different item. On init I would have to set number of colums. The bad part is that if one item has more text and would go on another line, the whole column would move down, but others won't.
2. Create a gridView, but I would have to hardcode or create more cases for every amount of products.

[image]

Is there any suggestion on how to implement this view in a better way?

Comment: I think your best option is: use a `RecyclerView` but each item would be a row. The first item at the top would be the one with all the photos, the next would be the header row with grey background etc. At least that's how I would implement it.

Comment: Then I would have a total of 3 well defined cases: image, groupTitle and groupChild. That seems easily achievable. Thanks! I'll give it a try, and will come back.

Comment: I ended up using `ScrollView` and programmatically adding elements depending on each case, as you suggested, because `RecyclerView` has too many functionalities I would not need, and it became too messy. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a GridLayout:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Here's a useful tutorial:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_in_XML_Layout_Resources

A GridView however is completely unsuitable for your needs. It can only show equal width items that overflow to the next row when the width of the GridView has been filled.